# Иcпользование трех моделей в ActiveDataProvider

Tags: yii2

Пытаюсь организовать фильтр поиска по нескольким моделям.У меня есть три модели Film, Mfilm,Serial возможно ли их использовать в любом из провайдеров и как (если есть ссылки будет просто здорово).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте свою выборку любым способом, слейте в один массив и используйте ArrayDataProvider вместо ActiveDataProvider.